# Rails 5.1 AJAX Load Database Object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am quite new to programming/Rails and am currently trying to asynchronously load a database object in my rails webapp.  I'm asking this because all of the guides I've seen on how to make ajax requests haven't been for rails 5.1 and don't deal with simply ajax rendering a partial that has a database object.

What I'm making is a quiz application.  Essentially, the desired behavior is that the user chooses a verb form, which renders a partial with the specified attributes of a random Vocab from the database and displays them on the page.

The user then puts the his answer in a text field and hits enter or a 'check' button which runs the js function 'check()' to make sure what's in the field matches the correct attribute, if it's correct it counts how many the user has correct and then does an AJAX call to the database to load another Vocab so that the user can try to answer another question.

So far what I have is the main page:

```
    <body>
<%= link_to "Start Vocab", vocab_path(:id), id: "vocab_link" %>
<%= render @vocab %>

<a href='#1' id='executer-button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='check()'>Check</a>


<%= form_tag(:remote => true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag("answer", nil, :onkeypress => 'check()') %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check", :type => 'button', :onclick => "check()") %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag(method: "get", remote: true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Select form") %>
  <%= select_tag "formID", "<option value = ""> Select a form: </option><option value = '1'>Non-past </option><option value = '2'>Plain Past </option><option value = '3'>Te Form </option><option value = '4'>I Form </option><option value = '5'>Ifs </option><option value = '6'>Potential </option><option value = '7'>Passive </option><option value = '8'>Causative </option><option value = '9'>Causative Passive </option><option value = '10'>Volitional </option><option value = '11'>Conjectural </option><option value = '12'>Alternative </option><option value = '13'>Imperative </option><option value = '14'>Honorific </option>".html_safe, :onchange => 'chooseForm()'%>
<% end %>

<div id="showValue"></div>

</body>
<div id = "after_submit">
  <p id = "number_correct"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function check(){

  var answer1 = document.getElementById("answer").value;
  var correct = 0;

  if (answer1 == document.getElementById("japaneseform").innerHTML ) {
    correct++;

  }
  document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " correct" ;
}

</script>
```

I have a partial _vocab.html.erb:

```
<% verb = @vocab %>

<div id="parts of speech">
  <div id = "multi_part_question">
    <p id = "japaneseform"></p>
    <p id = "casual"> </p>
    <p id = "hiragana"> </p>
    <p id = "english form"></p>
    <p id = "definition"> </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var js_verb = '<%= raw verb.to_json %>'

function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}

function rand(a, b) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a); }

var randomVerbObject = JSON.parse(js_verb)
var verbValuesArray = Object.values(randomVerbObject)
var arrayOfValues = [[1,2],[3,6],[7,10],[11,15],[16,16],[17,28],[29,32],[33,36],[37,44],[45,52],[53,56],[57,60],[61,64],[65,68],[69,72]];

function chooseForm(){

  var i = document.getElementById("formID").value;
  var randI = arrayOfValues[i];
  var randomizer = rand(randI[0],randI[1]);
  var japanese_form = verbValuesArray[randomizer];
  document.getElementById("showValue").innerHTML = randomizer;
  document.getElementById("casual").innerHTML = verbValuesArray[3];
  document.getElementById("hiragana").innerHTML = verbValuesArray[2];
  document.getElementById("english form").innerHTML = getKeyByValue(randomVerbObject, japanese_form);
  document.getElementById("definition").innerHTML =  verbValuesArray[1];
  document.getElementById("japaneseform").innerHTML = japanese_form;

}
</script>
```

I have a controller conjugationer_controller.rb:

```
class ConjugationerController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @vocab = Vocab.find(rand(1..190))


  end


  def show
    @vocab = Vocab.find(rand(1..190))

  end
end
```

and I have these routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'vocabs/show'
  post 'vocabs/id' => 'vocabs#show'
  post 'vocabs/show' => 'vocabs#show'
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :vocabs
  post 'conjugationer/index' => 'conjugationer#show'
  get 'conjugationer/index' => 'conjugationer'
  get 'conjugationer/show' => 'conjugationer#show'
 root 'conjugationer#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a bit about what function/method exactly are you calling? What you expect to happen? What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, what I'm referring to is:
<%= form_tag(:remote => true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag("answer", nil, :onkeypress => 'check()') %>
  <%= submit_tag("Check", :type => 'button', :onclick => "check()") %>
<% end %>

It runs the js function check(), I want to ajaxify it to make it re-render the partial when I call the check function and I have added :remote => true to the form.  I'm getting no errors, but I do not know how to reload the partial asynchronously.